# Sumif only from positive number

Tags: google-sheets

currently I were already able to create a working forumlar with the SUMIF

`=SUMIF(Units!K2:K183; "<=31.12.2015"; Units!X2:X183)`

This is working fine and showing me the total sum of the the entries in row X2 to X183 if the date in row K2 to K183 is before 31.12.2015.

But now I want to add some extra:
I want to sum only the positive values in row X2 to X183. So in row X are just Euro amounts listed like e.g. 30,00 €. And a few lines have negative amounts in it like -20,00 €. Those negative values I want to exclude from this SUM.

Is this possible?
Perhaps with some kind of filter function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for asking so fast. I found the solution myself:

```
=SUMIFS(Units!X2:X183; Units!K2:K183; "<=31.12.2015"; Units!X2:X183; ">0")
```

Just use the SUMIFS function and all works fine :-)